# array_combine(); not producing values properly

Tags: php, html, arrays, session

EDIT: Alright, my original post was kinda confusing, I've also tried something new. Here's my code:

```
if($_POST['submit']=='Save'){
    $_SESSION['quantity'] = $_POST['quantity'];

    $_SESSION['order'] = array_combine($_SESSION['parts-order'], $_SESSION['quantity']);

   header("Location: shopping.php");
    exit;
}
```

Both $_SESSION arrays are 430 long, both containing strings. When I print_r() on both $_SESSION arrays separately, they return their expected values. Basically, when I combine the arrays, I expect this output:

```
Array
(
    [1 inch ratchet tie down] => 13
    [24" White Ring Buoy w/ Reflective Tape] => 4
    [50' Throw Line w/bag] => 5
    [Classic Shirt Large] => 0
    ...
)
```

Y'know, or whatever values are in $_SESSION['quantity']. I, instead, get this:

```
Array
(
    [1 inch ratchet tie down] => 0
    [24" White Ring Buoy w/ Reflective Tape] => 0
    [50' Throw Line w/bag] => 0
    [Classic Shirt Large] => 0
    ...
)
```

Unless each of the $_SESSION['quantity'] values is the same, it produces 0. How do the values get changed to 0 in the process of array_combine?

Thanks.

Comment: What's your question? The title doesn't make much sense. Can you provide examples?

Comment: I included a link to github, basically am trying to create two arrays--one to hold each part description, and one to hold quantities for each part--and then combine them so that they print as parts=>quantity. I'm also trying to save everything in $_SESSION variables.

Comment: So, what? You're asking us to do it for you?

Comment: I'm asking what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: That is to say: I'm asking why I can't find & save quantities based on them being values in this key=>value array. Should I make $quant a session variable, for example? (Mostly I just need guidance, I'm a junior who graduated about 5 months ago, but I'm responsible for nearly of the programming where I work.)

Comment: Where do you set `$_SESSION['parts-order']` before combining it with `$_SESSION['quantity']`?

Comment: I set it with array_push($_SESSION['parts-order'], $row['dbDescription']);, line 684

Comment: Erica, I have taken a look at the lines you have mentioned, but I lack context about the problem. Can you tell us what errors do you receive accompanied with a stack trace if you receive an error? If you do not receive an error, can you tell us how the behavior you experience differs from the behavior you expect?

Comment: I updated it, thanks.